# How can i print only the columns with $("").printArea(); without to go in a new line for every column?

Tags: jquery, function, printing

If i have the printArea files and i got a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td class="print">Barcode</td><td class="print">Description</td><td>Price</td></td>
<tr><td class="print">0123456</td><td class="print">Gold Ring  </td><td>100 €</td></td>
</table>
```

How can i print only the columns with the class "print", without to go in a new line for every column?

Comment: For starters duplicate IDs are invalid HTML and will not work with jQuery... use classes instead e.g. `class="print"`.

Comment: done, but if i put the classes in the td tags, i don't see the table in line, in the printed page

Comment: That was only one issues, but cannot be avoided as duplicate IDs are invalid and jQuery can only see the first match. Are you able to post a full example? (e.g. in a JSFiddle or snippet)

Comment: the example is very complex to post, but i only need to print some columns (and not all) from the table, but in line. i don't want every column in a new line.